# Quais são as formas de iterar um array em PHP (sem foreach)?

Tags: php, foreach, while, for, iterator

Antes que eu seja censurado pela pergunta, aviso de antemão que o intuito da mesma é simplesmente a nível de curiosidade. Eu sei que o `foreach` é o meio mais adequado para isso.

Porém gostaria de saber o seguinte:

Quais são as formas de iterar com um `array` em PHP, sem a utilização do `foreach`, de maneira que possa acessar `índice` e o `valor` (como no `foreach`)?

Gostaria de ver exemplos com `for`, `while` ou até mesmo funções.

Vou deixar um `array` para modelo da resposta:

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);
```

Preciso que a interação se dê dessa forma (exemplificando com `foreach`):

```
foreach($array as $indice => $valor)
{
   var_dump($indice, $valor);
}
```

**Atenção**: O único caso não aceito para iteração com `for` é o do `$i++`, já que é uma maneira engessada e só serve para `array` com índices numéricos.

Comment: Seria interessante cada um que respondesse exemplificasse com apenas uma forma :)

Comment: xD preciso responder essa pergunta!

Comment: Eu não entendi bem como deve ser a saida, ele deve imprimir `tags` e depois `0`, `PHP`... ou so `0`, `PHP`?. pq estou esbarrando [nisso](https://ideone.com/wTtkY0)

Comment: Excelente pergunta, é muito legal ver que a comunidade é bem criativa para dar *N* soluções

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sendo também um novato, fiquei interessado na pergunta e encontrei um artigo interessante sobre a mesma.

Aqui vai uma solução de acordo com o artigo.

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);

$keys = array_keys($array);

$size = count($array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $key   = $keys[$i];
    $value = $array[$key];

    echo $value;

}
```

Veja o código funcionando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/FDYKuD)

Ref: [PHP internals: When does foreach copy?](https://nikic.github.io/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html)

Comment: Agora que entendi a sua iteração! Reparei a injustiça do _Down vote_. +1

Comment: Se me permite @IazyFox, dei um tapão na resposta

Comment: Estava a tentar fazer sem "indices" como tu comentaste `for (; isset($keys[0]); ) {
    $key   = $keys[0];
    $value = $array[$key];


 print($value);
    
 
 array_shift($keys);

}`  Mas sem muito sucesso, agora também estou sem  muito tempo :(

Comment: +1 por fazer com $i++, *for* quebrando paradigmas!!!rsrsrsr

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, a pergunta em si já é uma quebra de paradigmas (quiçá as respostas!) kkkk

Comment: Apesar de não ter uma "resposta certa", marquei essa pelos votos da maioria

Answer (score 15):

Também é possível iterar um array usando as funções, [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) ou [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), o primeiro argumento é o array que deseja iterar, o segundo é a função que deve ser aplicada em todos os elementos, essa função pode ser uma já declarada ou uma anônima(clousere)

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);

array_walk($array, function($v, $k) { 
    var_dump($v, $k);
});
```

No caso do `array_walk_recursive`, ele iterará com os elementos do `array` recursivamente.

Veja:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($value, $key) {
    var_dump($value, $key);
});
```

Resultado:

```
string(8) "Overflow"
string(5) "stack"
string(10) "Português"
string(9) "linguagem"
string(3) "PHP"
int(0)
string(10) "Iteração"
int(1)
string(5) "Array"
int(2)
```

Exemplo no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ElCl0r)

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/wTtkY0)

Comment: A ironia no caso é que a pergunta é sobre array, e o cara que responde chama @rray

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, lol a `@` é outra ironia também haha.

Comment: Que será que ele quis dizer?

Comment: Quem @WallaceMaxters?

Comment: Você quis atribuir o `@` ao fato do PHP omitir os erros com ele?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não, algumas linguaguens usa `@` para definir um array, por exemplo perl e powershell :D

Comment: Ah, tá. O `ruby` também. Mas parece que é para definir uma variável global

Answer (score 14):

Não me contive sem ter que dar a minha palinha por aqui

Uma outra boa forma de se fazer essa iteração de uma `array`, sem o `foreach`, seria com um `while`, iterando em cima de uma instância de `ArrayIterator`.

Veja:

```
 $it = new ArrayIterator($array);

 while ($it->valid()) {

    $indice = $it->key();

    $valor = $it->current();

    $it->next();
 }
```

Só lembrando que, pra fazer outra iteração, seria necessário utilizar o método `rewind` para retornar ao ponteiro ao início.

```
$it->rewind(); // Após o while
```

Answer (score 13):

Ainda falando de objetos poderíamos fazer assim também:

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);

$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($array);

$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

while($iterator->valid()) {
    echo $iterator->key() . ' => ' . $iterator->current() . "\n";

    $iterator->next();
}
```

Importante lembrar é que temos que utilizar o método `next` dentro do `while` para passar para o próximo elemento e, assim, evitar um **loop infinito**.

Que cairia na sua [própria resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81455/4995) referente ao  `ArrayIterator()`

Answer (score 12):

Você pode utilizar o [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk.php):

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);

array_walk($array, function ($value, $key){
    var_dump($key, $value);
});
```

Caso o índice seja irrelevante, [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) pode ser utilizado

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);

array_map(function($value)
{
    var_dump($value);
}, $array);
```

Comment: No caso do `array_map` não teria a `$key`, não é verdade ?

Comment: array_map desconsidera o índice.

Comment: Na verdade seu propósito é ser usado em conjunto com outros arrays, porém ele acaba iterando.

Answer (score 11):

Uma outra maneira de fazer isso é utilizando a função `each`.

Ela pega o ponteiro atual do `array` e transforma em outro `array`, contendo o valor do índice e valor desse `array`. Em seguida, ele passa para o próximo elemento do `array`.

Exemplo;

```
each($array);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Portugus
    [value] => Portugus
    [0] => linguagem
    [key] => linguagem
)
```

Veja que ele retorna uma chave chamada `value` e outra como índice numérico. Isso é para que seja possível utilizar essa função com o `list`.

Então podemos fazer isso:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
    var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

Podemos ainda utilizar (estranhamente) um `for` para isso:

```
for (; list($key, $value) = each($array); ) {
      var_dump($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: Não seria mais intuitivo usar um while uma vez que você está omitindo os dois parâmetros do for?

Comment: É verdade, @LuisHenrique. Ficou esquisitão mesmo a codificação. Porém foi só pra ter um exemplo mesmo :)

Comment: **Nota PHP 7.2**: a função [`each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) agora é obsoleta será removida no futuro.

Answer (score 10):

Você pode construir um *design patterns* de interação, conforme o exemplo abaixo, que é baseado no PHP Iterator ( http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.iterator.php ):

```
 <?php

   //entrada de elementos
    $myCollection = [
        new stdClass(),
        new stdClass(),
        new stdClass(),
        new stdClass(),
    ];
     /**
     * :::: Iterator Interface 
     *
     * @author ivan-ferrer
     */
    interface MyIteratorInterface
    {
        public function current();
        public function rewind();
        public function next();
        public function key();
        public function valid();
    }

    // Estruturais, Comportamentais e Criacionais
    // PHP Iterator

    class PHPIterator implements Iterator, MyIteratorInterface
    {
        private $collection = [];
        private $key        = 0;

        public function __construct(array $collection = [])
        {
            $this->collection = $collection;
        }

        public function rewind()
        {
            $this->key = 0;
        }


        public function current()
        {
            return $this->collection[$this->key];
        }

        public function key()
        {
            return $this->key;
        }

        public function next()
        {
            ++$this->key;
        }


        public function valid()
        {
            return isset($this->collection[$this->key]);
        }
    }

    $phpIterator = new PHPIterator($myCollection);

    echo "-----------------while--------------------\n";
    $phpIterator->rewind();

    while ($phpIterator->valid()) {
        var_dump($phpIterator->current());
        $phpIterator->next();
    }

    echo "-------------------for--------------------\n";


    for ($phpIterator->rewind(); $phpIterator->valid(); $phpIterator->next()) {
        var_dump($phpIterator->current());
    }


    echo "------------------foreach-----------------\n";

    foreach ($phpIterator as $key => $object) {
        var_dump($object);
    }
```

Há também diversas outras formas de fazer um **iterator**:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/spl.iterators.php

Comment: Também é uma forma válida. Mesmo que ninguém queira declarar uma classe só pra iterar, o importante é que estamos discutindo algo por curiosidade :)

Comment: Como assim ninguém? Eu acho que vale tanto para documentação como para preservar as regras de negócio de uma empresa. Além disso garante que seu código não perca seu objetivo de funcionalidade, garantindo consistência e boa interpretação de uso.

Comment: Falo para iterar com um `array`. O sentido da pergunta mesmo foi só por questão de curiosidade. Não há dúvidas que a melhor forma pra iterar com um simples `array` é usando o `foreach`.

Comment: O objetivo de uma Interface não é redeclaração de códigos, muito ao contrário disso, é para evitar "redeclarações", o objetivo é construir uma base sólida (um molde) para iniciar um projeto. Acho que você deveria estudar um pouco mais sobre `Interfaces` e classes abstratas, vai te ajudar a compreender melhor para que serve e pode ser que um dia você mude sua opinião...

Comment: eu acho que você não entendo o que eu quis dizer. A interface `Iterator` já contém os 5 métodos que você adicionou na sua interface. Não é o meu objetivo causar discussões longas, e sim só dar um toque quando a codificação da resposta. Eu sei pra que servem as interfaces e entendi perfeitamente o seu objetivo ao utilizadas (eu faço muito isso). Na verdade, pela sua implementação você só precisa do `Iterator` (que é nativo do PHP), nem precisa do `MyIterator`. Foi isso que quis dizer :|

Comment: Entendi sim @WallaceMaxters, mas não fez muito sentido para mim, quando você disse que estou "declarando meus métodos só para iterar", em uma empresa de alto nível de desenvolvimento, essa prática é muito bem aceita, se assim como eu, você tem vontade de crescer como desenvolvedor, eu recomendo usar Interfaces, mal não faz, creio que só tem a somar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27156/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-ivan-ferrer).

Answer (score 10):

É possível tratar-lo como objeto assim:

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);


$A = $array;
while(!is_null(key($A))) {
  var_dump(current($A));
  next($A);
}
```

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: Puts! eu imaginei que tinha como fazer essa do `key($array)`, porém com o `for` (não tinha dado certo). Importante complementar que o uso do `key` no seu caso foi corretíssimo, visto que `current` pode retornar outros valores considerados como boleanos `false`, causando a "pausa indesejada" da iteração

Comment: minha edição sugerida seria a seguinte: `while( ! is_null( $key = key($A)))`. Aí daria pra acessar o índice atual dentro do loop na iteração :)

Answer (score 8):

De fato, um loop `for` não trabalha bem com *arrays* com índices não numéricos, porém é possível contornar isso se *"resetar"* as *keys* caso mas mesmas não sejam importantes, com [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

```
$array = array(
    'stack' => 'Overflow',
    'linguagem' => 'Português',
    'tags' => array('PHP', 'Iteração', 'Array')
);

$numericArray = array_values($array);

$count = count($numericArray);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    var_dump($numericArray[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Pensando dessa forma, você poderia utilizar o `$i` com `array_values` e `array_keys`. O que acha de adicionar isso na resposta? `$keys = array_keys($meuArray); $keys[$i]; $arrays[$i];`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters nesse caso minha resposta seria muito parecida com uma já postada...

Comment: Entendi :). Mas de qualquer forma chora nesse [Ideone](http://ideone.com/kGLeis)

Answer (score 8):

Ok, só de sacanagem, vai a minha resposta:

```
print_r( $array );
```

Isso itera e já mostra na tela de uma vez só, tanto chaves quanto valores.

E o melhor ainda, funciona em *arrays* multi-nível ;)

<sup><sub>Ok, não tem como aproveitar os dados pra muitas coisas diferentes, mas se for só pra exibir, o `print_r` vem com "pacote completo".</sub></sup>

Answer (score 4):

Foi dito na [resposta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81470/4995) que `array_map` desconsidera o índice.

Porém, existe ainda uma outra forma muito interessante. É utilizando `array_map`, com multipos parâmetros. Sendo assim, podemos passar um array com as chaves, e o outro, para valores.

Assim:

```
$array = array('nome' => 'wallace', 'idade' => 25);

$map = function ($value, $key)
{
   echo "$key => $value";
}

array_map($map, $array, array_keys($array));
```

Relacionado: [Qual é a finalidade de array_map aceitar infinitos parâmetros do tipo array, depois do callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93894/qual-%C3%A9-a-finalidade-de-array-map-aceitar-infinitos-par%C3%A2metros-do-tipo-array-dep?s=2|0.6922)

Answer (score 3):

## Usando `do ... while`:

```
    do
    {
        $cliente = current($dados_teste); // acessa item atual com "current"
        $tabela.= $cliente['nome'] .'-'. $cliente['idade']; // usa os dados
    }            
    while(next($dados_teste)!==false); // avança o ponteiro com "next"
```

## Código de exemplo:

```
<?php

    $dados_teste = array(
                            array(
                                    'nome'=>'Pedro',
                                    'idade'=>'45',
                                    'uf'=>'RJ'
                                ),

                            array(
                                    'nome'=>'Maria',
                                    'idade'=>'30',
                                    'uf'=>'RJ'
                                ),    

                            array(
                                    'nome'=>'Miguel',
                                    'idade'=>'28',
                                    'uf'=>'MG'
                                ),    

                            array(
                                    'nome'=>'Paulo',
                                    'idade'=>'52',
                                    'uf'=>'SP'
                                ),                            
                        );


    $tabela = '<table>
        <tr><th>Nome</th><th>Idade</th><th>UF</th></tr>';

    do
    {
        $cliente = current($dados_teste);

        $tabela.= '
        <tr><td>'.$cliente['nome'] .'</td><td>'. $cliente['idade'] .'</td><td>'.  $cliente['uf'] .'</td></tr>';
    }            
    while(next($dados_teste)!==false);    

    $tabela.='
    </table>';   

?><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Exemplo Iterando array com Do...While</title>
    <style>
        table {border-collapse: collapse; }
        th,td { border:1px solid #777; padding:10px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $tabela; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

## Output:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Exemplo Iterando array com Do...While</title>
        <style>
            table {border-collapse: collapse; }
            th,td { border:1px solid #777; padding:10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><th>Nome</th><th>Idade</th><th>UF</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Pedro</td><td>45</td><td>RJ</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Maria</td><td>30</td><td>RJ</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Miguel</td><td>28</td><td>MG</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Paulo</td><td>52</td><td>SP</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```