# imprimir valor de determinado array com o PHP

Tags: php, array

Tenho esse array

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
  [product_image] => http://placehold.it/250x150/2aabd2/ffffff?text=Product+2 
  [product_name] => Product 2 
  [product_desc] => Product details 
  [product_size] => S 
  [product_price] => 5435.50 
  [product_id] => 145 
  [product_quantity] => 1 
  [unique_key] => 1504538986397 
) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
  [product_image] => http://placehold.it/250x150/2aabd2/ffffff?text=Product+1 
  [product_name] => Product 1 
  [product_desc] => Product details 
  [product_size] => S 
  [product_quantity] => 1 
  [product_price] => 2990.50 
  [product_id] => 12 
  [unique_key] => 1504539624302 
) 
[2] => stdClass Object ( 
 [product_image] => http://placehold.it/250x150/2aabd2/ffffff?text=Product+3 
  [product_name] => Product 3 
  [product_desc] => Product details 
  [product_size] => S 
  [product_price] => 5435.50 
  [product_id] => 145 
  [product_quantity] => 1 
  [unique_key] => 1504539625645 
) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( 
  [product_image] => http://placehold.it/250x150/2aabd2/ffffff?text=Product+6 
  [product_name] => Product 6 
  [product_desc] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  [product_size] => S 
  [product_price] => 5435.50 
  [product_id] => 145 
  [product_quantity] => 1 
  [unique_key] => 1504539627863 
) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( 
  [product_image] => http://placehold.it/250x150/2aabd2/ffffff?text=Product+5 
  [product_name] => Product 5 
  [product_desc] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  [product_size] => S 
  [product_price] => 3410.00 
  [product_id] => 155 
  [product_quantity] => 1 
  [unique_key] => 1504539628585 
) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( 
  [product_image] => http://placehold.it/250x150/2aabd2/ffffff?text=Product+4 
  [product_name] => Product 4 
  [product_desc] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  [product_size] => S 
  [product_price] => 435.50 
  [product_id] => 154 
  [product_quantity] => 1 
  [unique_key] => 1504539629309 
) 
)
```

Como faria para imprimir com o PHP o valor apenas do **[product_price]**?

Comment: algum das resposta serviu para você ???

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir somente o campo `product_price` que está em um `array` de ***objetos*** faça um [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), ***exemplo***:

```
$items = array(); // esse array é do pergunta

foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo $item->product_price;
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [Quais são as formas de iterar um array em PHP (sem foreach)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81446/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-formas-de-iterar-um-array-em-php-sem-foreach)
- [Laço foreach em PHP – Aula 20](https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2014/07/laco-foreach-em-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Como os dados estão dentro de um `array`, você precisara utilizar um `loop` como `for`, `foreach` ou `while`, veja abaixo um exemplo com `foreach`:

```
$dados = [];
foreach($dados as $item) {
    echo $item->product_price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que esse vetor está na variável *$vetor*.

Código para imprimir o preço de um item específico, por exemplo, do primeiro (posição 0):

```
echo $vetor[0]->product_price;
```

Código para imprimir o preço de todos os itens do vetor:

```
foreach ($vetor as $produto){
    echo "Valor: ". $produto->product_price."<br/>";
}
```