# Foreach dentro de outro array no php

Tags: php, foreach

Como eu posso gerar com o php esse array para fazer uma transação de pagamento pelo Pagseguro?

```
$params = array(
        'email'                     => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,  
        'token'                     => $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN,
        'creditCardToken'           => $creditCardToken,
        'senderHash'                => $senderHash,
        'receiverEmail'             => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
        'paymentMode'               => 'default', 
        'paymentMethod'             => 'creditCard', 
        'currency'                  => 'BRL',
        // 'extraAmount'               => '1.00',       

        'itemId1'                   => '0001',
        'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
        //'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
        'itemAmount1'               => '1.00',  
        'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

        'itemId2'                   => '0002',
        'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
        //'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
        'itemAmount2'               => '1.00',  
        'itemQuantity2'             => 1,           

        'reference'                 => 'REF1234',       
        'senderName'                => $senderName,
        'senderCPF'                 => $senderCPF,
        'senderAreaCode'            => 83,
        'senderPhone'               => $senderPhone,
        'senderEmail'               => $senderEmail,
        'shippingAddressStreet'     => $shippingAddressStreet,
        'shippingAddressNumber'     => $shippingAddressNumber,
        'shippingAddressDistrict'   => $shippingAddressDistrict,
        'shippingAddressPostalCode' => $shippingAddressPostalCode,
        'shippingAddressCity'       => $shippingAddressCity,
        'shippingAddressState'      => $shippingAddressState,
        'shippingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA',
        'shippingType'              => 1,
        'shippingCost'              => '1.00',
        'installmentQuantity'       => 1,
        'installmentValue'          => '3.00',
        'creditCardHolderName'      => 'Chuck Norris',
        'creditCardHolderCPF'       => '54793120652',
        'creditCardHolderBirthDate' => '01/01/1990',
        'creditCardHolderAreaCode'  => 83,
        'creditCardHolderPhone'     => '999999999',
        'billingAddressStreet'     => 'Address',
        'billingAddressNumber'     => '1234',
        'billingAddressDistrict'   => 'Bairro',
        'billingAddressPostalCode' => '58075000',
        'billingAddressCity'       => 'João Pessoa',
        'billingAddressState'      => 'PB',
        'billingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA'
    );
```

Note que precisa repetir de acordo com o numero de produtos essa parte

```
        'itemId1'                   => '0001', 
        'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
        //'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
        'itemAmount1'               => '1.00',  
        'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

        'itemId2'                   => '0002',
        'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
        //'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
        'itemAmount2'               => '1.00',  
        'itemQuantity2'             => 1,
```

Os produto vem de um array

```
foreach($product_list_array as $item)
{
    echo $item->product_price;
    echo $item->product_id;
    echo $item->product_quantity;
    echo $item->product_desc;

}
```

Como eu faria para colocar esse **foreach** dentro do **$params=array(...)** junto com as demais informações da compra?

Ficaria assim?

```
<?php 

$params = array();

$params['email']  = $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL;  
$params['token']  = $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN;

foreach($product_list_array as $index => $item)
{
    $item = 'itemId' . $index;
    $params[$item]  => $item->product_id,
    $params['itemDescription1'] = $item->product_desc,  
    $params['itemAmount1'] = $item->product_price,  
    $params['itemQuantity1'] = $item->product_quantity,
}

$params['billingAddressState'] => 'PB';
$params['billingAddressCountry'] => 'BRA';

$header = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8;');
    $response = curlExec($PAGSEGURO_API_URL."/transactions", $params, $header);
    $json = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)));

?>
```

está dando erro

Comment: Não precisa abrir outra pergunta para a mesma dúvida, [inclusive ela foi respondida aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234693/imprimir-valor-de-determinado-array-com-o-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$params['email']  = $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL;  
$params['token']  = $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN;
...

foreach($product_list_array as $index => $item)
{
    $item = 'itemId' . $index;
    $params[$item]  = $item->product_id;
    $params['itemDescription1'] = $item->product_desc; 
    $params['itemAmount1'] = $item->product_price;
    $params['itemQuantity1'] = $item->product_quantity;
}

...
$params['billingAddressState'] = 'PB';
$params['billingAddressCountry'] = 'BRA';
```

Comment: assim deu erro quando coloco dentro do $params();

Comment: tenta inicializar $params = array();

Comment: olha como eu fiz, editei minha resposta. está dando erro

Comment: No exemplo que eu te mandei eu coloquei [...] você completou com os outros parametros que eu pulei?
você pode verificar se todos os itens foram de forma correta colocando embaixo de $params['billingAddressCountry'] => 'BRA'; o comando:  var_export($params); die();, assim antes de executar a aplicação você aperta f12 vai na aba network e executa a aplicação, assim a aplicação vai parar no "die();" e na aba network você vai ter os valores do $params.

Comment: Sim eu coloquei os outros parametros, meu código está de acordo com a minha resposta onde diz "Ficou assim" está dando erro de php mesmo.

Comment: Qual é o erro? Tem como postar?

Comment: sim, está assim

https://imgur.com/a/EOe2N

Comment: A imagens não é do erro, e segundo o código que você enviou ele não esta com os outros parâmetros

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65085/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-wagner-martins-bodyboard).