# Existe alguma alternativa para o uso do for em php?

Tags: php, for

Existe alguma maneira de fazer em php o que o `for` faz, de forma diferente? Um método alternativo por exemplo, mas com o mesmo resultado que se conseguiria ao usar o `for`.

Exemplo de uso do `for`:

```
for($contador = 0; $contador < 10; $contador++)
{
    echo "O contador agora é: $contador";
}
```

Se existe, como e quais seriam essas maneiras?

Comment: Vai depender do que exatamente você quer fazer.

Comment: [Quais são as formas de iterar um array em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81446/91)

Comment: Eu não entendi a pergunta, poderia por favor explicar de outra forma?

Comment: De outra forma, sem usar o ```for``` para se obter o mesmo resultado, com meios alternativos @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @Florida experimentou `foreach`+`range()`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não, realmente não sei outra maneira de fazer isso, por isso queria saber como, se é possível e como seria feito. A pergunta pode não ser a melhor, mas todo o conhecimento é bem-vindo.

Comment: @Florida eu não negativei, até respondi pra ver se ajudava em algo :) - vou deixar o +1 pra ver se ajuda em algo. Estou pensando em uma maneira melhor de descrever a sua pergunta para quem saiba consigamos reverter esses downvotes.

Comment: Infelizmente tomei uma chuva de negativos, esperava ao menos nenhum positivo por ser algo simples, infelizmente vou ter que remover. Nada contra quem deu -1, mas podiam ao menos dizer o motivo, para que perguntas melhores possam ser feitas. No mais, gostei muito das respostas, realmente aprendi outra maneira se se fazer isso, o que é ótimo. Aprender é legal.

Comment: @Florida, tentei pesquisar algo semelhante aqui no SOpt e não encontrei. Ao meu ver a pergunta está clara, embora simples demais. Talvez ajude futuramente. Intrigante é que há apenas uma sinalização, o que não ajuda muito a entender os negativos.

Comment: Eu não dei -1, ainda assim acho a questão demasiado vaga, e provavelmente esse será o motivo. "Existe outra forma de fazer isto?", mas o exemplo é demasiado abstrato e a real intenção do código não é clara, e dá a intender que será bem mais do que está escrito. Mostrar o que realmente está a tentar fazer seria melhor e provavelmente teria atraído mais positivos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu não entendi bem a pergunta, mas se a ideia é ter de 1 a 10, ou de 1 a 100, ou de 50 a 200, sempre baseado em numeros e incrementando então pode simplesmente usar o `range()` do proprio PHP, exemplo:

```
$foo = range(1, 10);

print_r($foo);
```

Então poderá usar com `foreach` ou até mesmo `implode`, exemplos:

### foreach

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $contador) {
     echo "O contador agora é: {$contador}.";
}
```

### implode

```
$foo = range(1, 10);

$baz = 'O contador agora é: ';

echo $baz . implode('. ' . $baz, $foo) . '.';
```

---

### Sobre o range

A função `range()` do PHP não gera array apenas numericas, por exemplo se fizer algo como:

```
range('a', 'e');
```

Isto irá gerar um array assim:

```
array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

E pode fazer ao contrário também:

```
range('z', 'a');
```

Isto irá gerar um array assim:

```
array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
```

Que vai gerar um array assim:

```
Array
(
    [0] => z
    [1] => y
    [2] => x
    [3] => w
    [4] => v
    [5] => u
    [6] => t
    [7] => s
    [8] => r
    [9] => q
    [10] => p
)
```

Ou seja, `range` funciona para números e letras e pode-se inverter a ordem.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode obter o mesmo resultado utilizando o `while` com um contador e uma condição que seriam utilizadas no `for`, assim:

```
$contador = 0;
while($contador < 10) {
    echo "O contador agora é: " . $contador . "";
    $contador++;
}
```

Tecnicamente, em algumas linguagens pré-compiladas, o comando `for` é convertido para um comando `while` seguindo essa estrutura acima. Enfim, não deixa de ser uma opção.