# Array com indices aleatorios

Tags: php, array, random

Tenho um array randômico que retorna diversas chaves e necessito de manipular todos os dados retornados, o problema é que eles variam conforme a ocasião,desejo exibir essas informações organizadas no HTML, mas há casos em que essa array retorna mais valores, ou até mesmo nada ou faltam chaves ou são adicionadas mais chaves. Dessa forma não posso especificar no código que informação vai em que lugar pois se o índice não existir ficara vazio e ira gerar um Warning. De que forma posso manipular um array como esse ? exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou com `foreach($vizinho as $indice => $valor)`?

Comment: Relacionada: [Quais são as formas de iterar um array em PHP (sem foreach)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81446/5878)