# Como utilizar each e list em uma array multidimensional

Tags: php, array

Eu preciso percorrer toda a *array* multidimensional com `each` e `list` apenas. Este é o código:

```
$Carros = array(
    array("BMW", 130000, "Novo"),
    array("Strada", 40000, "Usado"),
    array("CRUZE", 100000, "Semi-novo")
);
```

Comment: E como tentou fazer?

Comment: Bom, eu sei fazer em uma array simples, mas em uma multidimensional, eu não tenho ideia de como fazer. Fiz algumas pesquisas e não encontrei muita coisa, por isso gostaria de saber como funciona em uma array multidimensional

Comment: Você precisará fazer dois laços: um para percorrer os valores de `$Carros`, outro para percorrer todos os valores de cada linha de `$Carros`.

Comment: Eu utilizo dois eachs para isso?

Comment: Sim, em laços de repetição distintos.

Comment: Tem como eu fazer isso sem laço de repetiçãow

Comment: [Quais são as formas de iterar um array em PHP (sem foreach)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81446/5878)