# Como o foreach do PHP funciona?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Para clarificar, esta pergunta **não é** sobre quando o `foreach` é utilizado ou quais as diferenças dele para [outros laços de repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81446/5878), mas sim sobre o funcionamento do `foreach` em si.

---

Na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), pouco se fala sobre como exatamente o `foreach` funciona, atentando-se mais em como utilizá-lo. Algumas frases soltas parecem ser uma tentativa de detalhar um pouco melhor, mas fora de um contexto específico elas acabam não agregando muito.

A citar:

> No PHP 7, o foreach não utiliza o ponteiro interno do array.

Isto é, podemos alterar livremente o ponteiro interno do *array* dentro do laço do `foreach` sem interferir na sua execução.

**Teste 1: Reiniciando o ponteiro interno do *array* a cada iteração não faz o laço reiniciar**

```
$arr = range(1, 5);

foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
    reset($arr);
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DrabMiserableMigration) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/D0nDA6)</sup>

Mesmo reiniciando o ponteiro interno do *array* o laço é finalizado normalmente.

> Para modificar diretamente elementos de um array dentro de um laço, preceda $value com &.

O que, a princípio, indica que o `foreach` não cria uma cópia do *array* para utilizar durante o laço, pois a referência no elemento seria uma referência ao elemento na cópia e não mais no *array* original. Mas o que vemos na prática é que a referência aponta para o elemento original.

**Teste 2: Referência do elemento aponta para o elemento do *array* original e não para uma cópia do mesmo**

```
$arr = range(1, 5);

foreach($arr as &$item) {
    $item *= 2;
}

print_r($arr);
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/InvolvedLightcoralBuckets) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ZAemC0)</sup>

Porém, podemos ver na prática que o *array* utilizado pela estrutura de repetição não é exatamente o *array* original, pois podemos alterar livremente o *array* sem interferir no laço.

**Teste 3: Alterando o *array* original dentro do `foreach` não altera o comportamento do laço**

```
$arr = range(1, 5);

foreach($arr as $item) {
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
    $arr[] = $item;
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/CulturedPeachpuffModularity) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/mXw3Fn)</sup>

Neste exemplo, a cada iteração adicionamos um elemento novo no final do *array*. Se o `foreach` utilizasse a própria referência de `$arr`, o laço seria infinito, mas o que acontece na prática é que somente os itens originais são iterados.

Resumindo:

1. O teste 1 mostra que o ponteiro utilizado pelo `foreach` não é o ponteiro do *array*;
2. O teste 2 mostraria que o `foreach` não faz uma cópia do *array*, pois a referência aponta para o elemento do *array* original, não um *array* de cópia;
3. O teste 3 mostra que o `foreach` faz, de fato, uma cópia do *array*, pois alterações feitas dentro do laço não se refletem no *array* original;

Os testes 2 e 3, principalmente, são, a princípio, contraditórios, pois um se comporta como cópia, enquanto o outro não.

Então a pergunta é: como o `foreach` do PHP funciona?

<sub>Se o comportamento da estrutura for diferente entre versões da linguagem e compará-las tornaria a resposta demasiadamente grande, aceita-se que seja respondido sobre seu funcionamento na versão mais atual.</sub>

Comment: Essa pergunta foi feita com base em uma dúvida própria, auxiliada por uma [discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46837135#46837135) e inspirada na pergunta [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10057671/1452488)

Comment: A resposta aceita do fórum em inglês, do link em teu comentário, não é suficientemente boa para ti?

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado a ideia é justamente trazer esse tipo de conteúdo (ou melhor, até) para o nosso site, em português.

Comment: hmmm, entendi... Realmente enriqueceria  o site...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, além do que, muitos não entenderão a resposta do SOen por estar em língua inglesa. A iniciativa do Anderson é boa e estou ansioso por uma resposta em portugues! :)

Answer (score 10):

Pesquisei um pouco sobre e cheguei a seguinte conclusão.,

> Teste 1: Reiniciando o ponteiro interno do array a cada iteração não
>   faz o laço reiniciar

A - Tradução aproximada:

> Antes do PHP 7, o ponteiro interno do array era modificado enquanto um
>   array estava sendo iterado com foreach . Isso não é mais o caso...
>   https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach.array-pointer
>   O item abaixo complementa:

B - Tradução aproximada:

> Quando usado no modo de valor por padrão, o foreach agora operará em uma cópia do array que está sendo iterado em vez do próprio array. Isso significa que as alterações feitas na matriz durante a iteração não afetarão os valores que são iterados.
>   https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach.by-value

Ou seja o foreach atua sobre a cópia do array. Se o array "copiado" possuir 2 itens, serão iterados esses dois itens e caso você manipule (como nos exemplos citados, o array inicial(a cópia) não será alterada).
Seria algo semelhante a isso:

```
$arrayA = ['AAA','BBB'];
$arrayB = $arrayA;//o foreach faz algo semelhante/equivalente a isso
//equivale a
foreach($arrayB as $k=> $b){
//foreach($arrayA as $k=> $b){
    $arrayA[] = 'A_B'.$b; 
}
print_r($arrayA);
```

Logo se eu percorrer `$arrayB` alterando os valores de `$arrayA` , `$arrayB` não terá seu conteúdo modificado.

No exemplo extraído da doc do PHP tem um exemplo de que ao usar o reset o ponteiro não reseta o ponteiro interno da cópia do array.

```
<?php
$array = [0, 1, 2];
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    var_dump(current($array));
}
```

https://ideone.com/gencKc

> Teste 2: Referência do elemento aponta para o elemento do array
>   original e não para uma cópia do mesmo

O foreach itera sobre a cópia do array original, independente de alterações nos valores durante o looping/iteração. Qualquer alteração será feita mas a cópia do array permanecerá intacta.
Não tenho conhecimento para falar de como o PHP armazena essa matriz original para que o foreach itere sobre mas no exemplo que citei de $arrayA e $arrayB (bem tosco) seria (ao meu ponto de vista) o modo que o foreach "administre" tudo isso.

Referências sobre o foreach:
https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach

***Up.
Para reforçar o que eu defendi no post

```
$arr = ['a' => 'AAA','b'=> 'BBB','c'=>'CCC'];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    echo  "$k: $v\n";
    $arr['c']= 'DDDDDD'; 
    print_r($arr);
   //Se o foreach não usasse a cópia do array para fazer a iteração,a 
   // chave c teria esse valor na última iteração($k = 'c')
}
print_r($arr);
```

Estou ansioso para discussões construtivas.

Comment: Saudações, Marcos, desculpe-me pela demora do feedback, estava esperando para ver se apareceriam outras respostas e analisar todas juntas. Se entendi bem, muito do que você colocou na sua resposta já estava explícito na própria pergunta, só que com outras palavras. A questão é, de fato, se o PHP opera sobre uma cópia do *array*, como pode a referência atuar sobre o *array* original e não sobre a cópia?  E quando é por referência, por que mesmo assim o ponteiro interno do *array* não é modificado, se, teoricamente, estou iterando o próprio objeto? Como o PHP gerencia tudo isso?

Comment: Perfeito. Talvez eu tenha me perdido na explicação hehe. Estou estudando um pouco mais sobre para ver se consigo ser mais técnico e realmente contribuir (não só discutir). Falta tempo pra mim

Answer (score 0):

A forma para que você consiga "cercar o frango" é chamar o endereço de fato de cada valor iterado &$item, e não a sua cópia $item. E isso não ocorre olhando para o array em si, mas sim para cada item iterado.

```
<pre>
<?php
$arr = range(1, 5);

// Repare que agora com a referência do endereço de fato, o array é alterado.
echo "O primeiro caso NÃO ALTERA o array.".PHP_EOL;
foreach($arr as $item) {
    var_dump($item=5);
    print_r($arr);
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
    reset($arr);
}

// Repare que agora com a referência do endereço de fato, o array é alterado.
echo "O segundo caso ALTERA o array.".PHP_EOL;
foreach($arr as &$item) {
    var_dump($item=5);
    print_r($arr);
    echo $item, PHP_EOL;
    reset($arr);
}
?>
</pre>
```

Pra complementar, na verdade sim, é uma cópia que ele faz, mas não do array, mas sim de cada valor iterado.

Comment: Discordo sobre a cópia do valor iterado. Veja o motivo https://ideone.com/RimDEK
<?php
$array = [0];
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    var_dump($val);
    $array[1] = 1;
    $array[2] = 2;
}

Comment: E por isso também https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach.by-value