# Como funciona internamente os arrays do PHP?

Tags: php, array, característica-linguagem

O PHP lida com *arrays* de uma forma diferentes de outras linguagens, aparentemente existe conceitos de *hashtable* para associar os valores. Como funciona internamente no core da linguagem os *arrays*?

Comment: Sua postagem venho bem a calhar com essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/331276/como-o-foreach-do-php-funciona/332160?noredirect=1#comment676248_332160
Até agora não cheguei a uma conclusão(até pela correria)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O PHP tem algo chamado *array* associativo e internamente é alguma forma de [*hashtable*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27827/101) mesmo, portanto ele consegue ter chaves esparsas, de tipos diferentes de dados e possui [complexidade O(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101) para quase todas operações básicas, assim como o *array* normal. Na verdade essa complexidade é tipicamente O(1), ela pode ser até O(n), mas na prática nem chega perto de acontecer. Obviamente que a chave do índice é calculada por uma [função *hash*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184019/101) padrão da linguagem ou especializada nos tipos primitivos dela.

Na verdade quase tudo na estrutura de dados geral e organização da memória é controla por tabelas de espalhamento (*hashtable*), de [forma análoga com JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101), mas isso não é tão visível e tão linear quanto em JS que tudo é um objeto criado em cima de uma *hashtable*.

Há uma otimização para obter a ordem já que um objeto *hashtable* puro não pode mostrar dados em uma ordem específica, então há um custo extra de armazenamento para a varredura em ordem funcionar. Veja como é a estrutura atual (se já não mudou), ela tem ponteiros para conseguir manter a ordem de entrada através de uma [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101) dos *buckets*:

```
typedef struct _hashtable {
    uint nTableSize;
    uint nTableMask;
    uint nNumOfElements;
    ulong nNextFreeElement;
    Bucket *pInternalPointer;
    Bucket *pListHead;
    Bucket *pListTail;
    Bucket **arBuckets;
    dtor_func_t pDestructor;
    zend_bool persistent;
    unsigned char nApplyCount;
    zend_bool bApplyProtection;
#if ZEND_DEBUG
    int inconsistent;
#endif
} HashTable;
```

E o `bucket` que mostra como é ineficiente (é quase inacreditável o tamanho do desperdício, em arquitetura 64 bits cada entrada ocupa 72 bytes só na tabela, ainda tem custo adicional em **cada** elemento que é próximo disso):

```
typedef struct bucket {
    ulong h;
    uint nKeyLength;
    void *pData;
    void *pDataPtr;
    struct bucket *pListNext;
    struct bucket *pListLast;
    struct bucket *pNext;
    struct bucket *pLast;
    const char *arKey;
} Bucket;
```

De forma geral os valores são alocados bem ineficientemente em PHP, os *arrays* não poderiam ser diferentes, embora tenha tido um esforço de otimização recentemente.

Por exemplo, descobri que todo valor é armazenado assim:

```
typedef union _zvalue_value {
    long lval;  /* long value */
    double dval;  /* double value */
    struct {
        char *val;
        int len;
    } str;
    HashTable *ht;  /* hash table value */
    zend_object_value obj;
} zvalue_value;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Array.c).

Em 64 bits esta estrutura terá 16 bytes porque o `len` está aí e não junto da *string* em si, então qualquer valor que não seja *string* desperdiçará 8 bytes por causa do [alinhamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183287/101). Claramente a estrutura foi pensada para 32 bits que desperdiça nada. Então rodar PHP em 64 bits pode ter quase o dobro do consumo de memória que em 32 bits, pra zero ganho. Quem sabe um dia resolvam isso, eles demonstram vontade.

Nem dá para dar tantos detalhes justamente porque o funcionamento interno é detalhe de implementação, e nada impede de passar funcionar de forma bem diferente.

E se tudo isso é estranho para você, sugiro começar estudar um pouco mais de ciência da computação, em especial estrutura de dados. Um pouco de C ajuda entender esses códigos dos *internals* do PHP.